# Synchronization in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, russian

I use TeXstudio to create LaTeX files. When the files are in English, there is synchronization between PDF file and LaTeX files: I click on PDF, the LaTeX source  scrolls automatically to the corresponding place. When the text is in Russian this feature does not work. There is no "Synchronise PDF" in the dropdown menu any more. Is it possible to make it work in Russian as well?

Comment: Have you checked if the issue is specific to TeXstudio? Maybe there is an issue with language support.

Comment: How to check it? What do you  mean? PDF looks good.

Comment: No use of another TeX editor or an external PDF viewer that also supports SyncTex.

Comment: Would you, please, advice another TeX editor or external PDF viewer, which support SyncTex?  Did  you hear if somebody used SyncTeX with Russian texts at all? May be, it is a problem of SyncTex?